# How can I have a StackPanel Inside a MenuFlyoutItem in windows 8.1 app xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

The MenuFlyout is defined like this. I don't want just Text, to be set in the MenuFlyoutItem, I want to have a StackPanel in it that could hold an Image and a TextBox.

```
<MenuFlyout x:Key="HeaderMenuFlyout">
        <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="CornflowerBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
        </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Cloud"
                        Tag="Cloud" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="This PC" Tag="This PC"/>

    </MenuFlyout>
```

How would I do this? This is an example
[image: From the OneDrive Windows 8.1 app]

Comment: Do you really need a MenuFlyout? Or you can just use a flyout?

Answer (score 6):

This would be a quick but dirty way.

```
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Hello" >
 <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Clock" />
    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />                    
   </StackPanel>
  </ControlTemplate>
 </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
</MenuFlyoutItem>
```

Or you can extend the MenuflyoutItem and add another dependency property for the image/symbol so that it's not hard coded in the template.

Comment: Maybe you need to extract the actual style of MenuFlyoutItem. You can do that using blend.